# How to replace every occurrence of [1]-[99] in Microsoft Word 2015?

Tags: microsoft-word, search, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2016

I am trying to search for any positive integer between 1 and 99
that is inside square brackets, like **[1]** or **[24]**. 
So basically every instance of: open square brackets, a number from 1 to 99, close square brackets. 
Or sometimes ranges / pairs of numbers like **[26-29]** or even **[30,31]**. 
I have to replace all the instances of square brackets with normal parentheses; e.g., **[1]** would be replaced with **(1)**,
**[42]** would be replaced with **(42)**, etc.

I've looked at `[1-9]{1,}` and `[1-9]{1,99}`

Plus I have to change every instance of **I** to **We** because I wrote a 30-page article and a colleague of mine suddenly joined to help out on the work, so...

Apparently according to this [documentation](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html), there is the following approach:

- <, >: Positional Anchors

But somehow I cannot get round it. Any help is highly appreciated as I have to end it by today.

---

**Note**: Microsoft Word for Mac Version 15.12.3

Comment: (1) What is your question?  (1a) That’s not searching for numbers between 1 and 99, it’s searching for natural numbers (positive integers) (between 1 and infinity) that don’t contain any zeroes.  But that’s a misleading oversimplification; if your document contains `131072`, that will find the `131` and the `72`.  (And actually, even *that* is an oversimplification, but I’m rambling.)  (2) Search for `<I>` and replace with `We`.  What is your question?

Comment: You are right about about `{1, }` which actually refers to 1 and infinity. I updated my question @G-Man. My question is how can I search for any positive integer between 1 and 99 that is inside square brackets like **[1]** or **[24]** sometimes **[26-29]** or even **[30,31]**. I have to replace all the instances of square brackets with normal parenthesis e.g. **(** 11 **)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go into “Find and Replace”, click on “More > >”, and click “Use wildcards”.

  (But you already knew that, right?)
- To search, literally, for a character
  that has special meaning in the wildcard (pattern matching) syntax,
  precede it with backslash (`\`). 
  So, to search for (literal) square brackets in the text, use `\[` and `\]`.
- Zero is a valid digit, so you must use `[0-9]` instead of `[1-9]`.

  - If you have languages other than English in your document,
    and particularly if you have alphabets other than the Roman alphabet
    (e.g., Arabic or Chinese),
    `[0-9]` *might* match numbers in those foreign alphabets. 
    (Or maybe even *letters* and other symbols in those foreign alphabets.) 
    It *might* be safer to use `[0123456789]`.
- So, to match any whole number (non-negative integer),
  use `[0-9]{1,}` or `[0-9]@`.
- To match any integer between 0 and 99, use `[0-9]{1,2}`.

  - This will match `0`. 
    If ***not*** matching `0` is important to you, say so.
  - This will also match two-digit numbers with a leading zero
    (i.e., `01`, `02`, `03`, ... `09`). 
    And, for that matter, `00`. 
    Again, say whether this is a serious problem.
- Use parentheses ( `(`…`)` ) to delimit capture groups or expressions.

So, a simple search for a one- or two-digit number in square brackets,
use `\[[0-9]{1,2}\]`.

But, if you want to do a Find and Replace,
and replace `[42]` with `(42)`,
then find `\[([0-9]{1,2})\]` and replace with `(\1)`. 
This is a little confusing. 
In the “Find what” string (expanded for clarity):

```
\[    (    [0-9]{1,2}    )    \]
      ↑                  ↑
```

the parentheses (highlighted) delimit a capture group. 
In the “Replace with” string:

```
(    \1    )
```

the parentheses are the literal parentheses characters
that you want to insert,
and `\1` says “take what the first capture group matched
(i.e., the number, without the brackets), and insert it here”.

To do the same thing with ranges of numbers,
just find `\[[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\]` (and, again, replace with `(\1)`. 
Ditto for comma-separated pairs of numbers:
`\[[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{1,2}\]`.

---

  To give another example of parentheses in Find and Replace
  (one that is, hopefully, clearer), suppose you have the text

```
Jack loves cats.
```

and you “Find”

```
Jack loves (*s).
```

and “Replace with”

```
(But Jill hates \1.)
```

the result is

```
(But Jill hates cats.)
```

---

As to the second part of the question:
to change every instance of **I** to **We**,
search for `<I>` and Replace All with `We`. 
And, unless your entire document is written in title case,
do a second pass, searching for `<We>` (title case),
and replace with `we` (lower case)
wherever it’s not the first word of a sentence.

Practically,
it may be less work to search for `<I>`
and Replace All with `we` (lower case),
and then do a second pass, searching for `<we>` (lower case),
and replacing with `We` (title case)
wherever it ***is*** the first word of a sentence. 
It might be possible to do this automatically with wildcards,
along the lines of

```
^013we>         ⇒   ^pWe
```

and

```
([.\!?] @)we>   ⇒   \1We
```

but I haven’t tested this thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**:

I found something really useful in this [blog](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-ways-to-batch-delete-brackets-and-inside-spaces-in-your-word-document/):

- `\[*\]`

This will find brackets and all enclosed texts. Same goes for parenthesis:

- `\(*\)`